# Firestore Rules - "exists" function not found when it's inside another function

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have a function in my firestore rules that check if a given document exists:

```
function doesDocExists(docId) {
  return exists(/databases/$(database)/documents/mycollection/$(docId))
}
```

and in the rules, I write:

```
allow create: if ... && doesDocExists(docId);
```

The problem is that Firestore fails to locate the function `exists`:

[image]

[image]

But if I write `allow create: if exists(...)` then it works.

Comment: Could you share your full security rules code, and not only parts of it.